# Do the subnets x.x.x.128/25 and x.x.x.192/26 collide? Why or why not?

Tags: subnet

I am working with a vpc  cidr of /23, and need to divvy up some public and private subnets for hosts, load balancers availability zones etc. please bear with this newbie question
Please assume I am talking about the last portion of the IP where needed

If I wanted a block of 16 and a block of 32 how would I do it?
A 0/28 would get me a block of 16.. and this will imply further blocks of 16/28, 32/28 etc, unless I have the wrong notion
If I wanted a block of 32 in addition to this, would it be correct to specify 0/27 ? Or would this collide with 0/28? What is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they overlap, if you’re using the same third octet. If you aren’t, they won’t.

If, for example, your /23 is `10.0.0.0/23`, it gives you `10.0.0.0-10.0.1.255`.

For example, if you use a different third octet:

```
10.0.0.128/25 gives you 10.0.0.128-10.0.0.255
10.0.1.192/26 gives you 10.0.1.192-10.0.1.255
```

So, there is no overlap.

But, for example, if you use the same third octet:

```
10.0.1.128/25 gives you 10.0.1.128-10.0.1.255.
10.0.1.192/26 gives you 10.0.1.192-10.0.1.255
```

So, half of the /25 overlaps with the /26.

For the record, AWS won’t allow you to enter them like that because of the overlap - they will force you to change one or both of them.

As for your other question of /27 and /28, you need to account for the network and broadcast addresses taking up 2 of your addresses in each of those. So, while /27 does have 32 addresses, only 30 are usable for hosts. The same would go for /28 (16 total with 14 usable host addresses).  So, you need 16 and 32 **usable** addresses, you would have to use a /27 and /26, respectively, since those are the mask sizes that can accommodate those host counts with minimal waste.

Let’s again say your /23 is `10.0.0.0/23`:

If you want to break it up into /27 and /28 blocks and use the same third octet, you could use:

```
10.0.1.0/27 for one block
10.0.1.32/28 for the other block
```

If you want to break it up into /26 and /27 blocks and use the same third octet, you could use:

```
10.0.1.0/26 for one block
10.0.1.64/27 for the other block
```

If you want to break it up into /27 and /28 blocks and use a different third octet, you could use:

```
10.0.0.0/27 for one block
10.0.1.32/28 for the other block
```

If you want to break it up into /26 and /27 blocks and use a different third octet, you could use:

```
10.0.0.0/26 for one block
10.0.1.64/27 for the other block
```

There are more combinations you could potentially use - these are just examples.